# Using find_if - How to include current item in predicate?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a `<list>` of objects of class `Reservation`. Each `Reservation` object holds a pointer to a `Customer` object and a `Bike` object.

What I'd like to know is: Is there a `Reservation` for a certain `Customer` in the `<list>`? I have one of `Customer`'s attributes, the `phone_number` to identify the customer.

I tried to achieve that via `find_if` but I don't know if or how I can access the object that is currently being checked by `find_if`.

**pseudo-code:**

```
found = (find_if(begin, end, iterator→customer→phonenumber == phone_number), != end)
```

**current approach:**

```
    bool found = (find_if(reservation_list.begin(), reservation_list.end(), customer->get_phone_number() == telefonnummer) != res_list.end());
```

The `customer->get_phone_number()` part is nonsense as it refers to a customer object pointer declared a few lines above, but not the current iterator.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap the check in a lambda: `[&telefonnummer](auto& customer){ return customer->get_phone_number() == telefonnummer;}`.

Comment: Doc of [`std::find`/`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) has usage examples.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lambda function to check if there is a `Reservation` for a certain `Customer` in the `<list>` by comparing the `phone_number`

```cpp
std::string telefonnummer ="";
auto is_target = [&telefonnummer](const Reservation &reservation) {
  return reservation.customer->get_phone_number() == telefonnummer;
};

bool found = (find_if(reservation_list.begin(), reservation_list.end(),
                      is_target) != res_list.end());
```

Comment: I get an error: error: expected expression
                        auto is_target = [&telefon...
                                                    ^

Comment: @Franz: The idea in this question is correct, the precise wording would depend on the details of your classes (which you left out). Just to check if you have at least C++11, try `auto test = [ ] ( ) { };` - the empty lambda function.

Comment: @Msalters I left it out because I translated my variable names for better understanding. `gcc --version`
 says 13.1.6 and I get the same error with the empty lambda function.

Comment: @Franz: `gcc --std=c++11` (or `c++14`, `c++17`, `c++20`).

Comment: @Jarod42 does not work clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
Changing the Cpp Standard in VSCode to C++17 also does not change anything.

Comment: *"linker command failed"* that is another error. Linker error happens after compile error, so you advance.